# Issue in populating dynamic data to dropdown column using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I am trying to populate and append a column For Example:Id with the below column data dynamically using jquery and ajax.

The data will be populated via rest webservice. But the data is not  getting populated.

The code snippet is as below.

The code which is pasted may not work properly due to lack of dynamic  data from a webservice.

So the issue lies in populating/appending the data into the column in the header.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // DO GET
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/customer/all",
    success: function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, customer) {

        var customerRow = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" +
          customer.id + "</td><td>" +
          customer.name.toUpperCase() + "</td><td>" +
          customer.age + "</td><td>" +
          customer.address.street + "</td><td>" +
          customer.address.postcode + "</td></tr>";

        $('#IdProof').append('<option value="' + customer.id + '">' + customer.age + '</option>');

        $('#customerTable tbody').append(customerRow);
      });

    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("ERROR: ", e);
      console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    }
  });

  $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      // Iterate each checkbox
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });

  $('#reboot').click(function() {
    $('#customerTable').find('tr').each(function(i) {
      var row = $(this);
      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
          Id = $tds.eq(1).text(),
          name = $tds.eq(2).text(),
          age = $tds.eq(3).text();
        // do something with productId, product, Quantity
        alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nId: ' + Id +
          '\nname: ' + name +
          '\nage: ' + age);

      }
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#inputFilter").on("keyup", function() {
      $("#select-all").hide();
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#customerTable > tbody > tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

      });
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Spring Boot - DELETE-UPDATE AJAX Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jqueryScript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{/css/main.css}" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Filter Table</h2>
    <div class="row col-md-7 ">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px; background-color: green; color: white;">
        <p>
          Type some text to search the table for <strong>Id</strong>, <strong>Name</strong>,
          <strong>Age</strong>, <strong>Street</strong>, <strong>PostCode</strong>:
        </p>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputFilter" type="text" placeholder="Search.." />
      </div>
      <table id="customerTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></th>
            <th>
              <select name="IdProof" id="id" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Id</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th>
              <select name="Name" id="name" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Name</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th>
              <select name="Age" id="age" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Age</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th>
              <select name="Street" id="street" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Street</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th>
              <select name="Postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Postcode</option>
              </select>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button id="reboot">Reboot</button>
      <button id="logs">Logs</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the data is not getting populated.` ? back end is not returning data or javascript is failing to populate the table

Comment: The data which is populated in the datatable will be from a webservice which is not avaialble.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your code like this. I think problem is in your concatination. Make all the concatenations like these

```
var customerRow = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" +
  customer.id + "'</td><td>'" +
  customer.name.toUpperCase() + "'</td><td>'" +
  customer.age + "'</td><td>'" +
  customer.address.street + "'</td><td>'" +
  customer.address.postcode + "'</td></tr>'";
```